# Bash Parse Arrays From Config File

Tags: arrays, linux, bash, parsing, configuration-files

I need to have an array for each "section" in the file containing:

```
[array0]
value1=asdf
value2=jkl

[array1]
value1=1234
value2=5678
```

I want to be able to retrieve these values like this:

```
echo ${array0[value1]}
echo ${array0[value2]}

echo ${array1[value1]}
echo ${array1[value2]}
```

Any thoughts on how to accomplish this? (Explanations would be a bonus)

I've already read these anwsers but none do exactly what I want to do.

[Read a config file in BASH without using "source"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4434797/read-a-config-file-in-bash-without-using-source)

[BASH Parsing variables from config file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16571739/bash-parsing-variables-from-config-file)

[Array like data structure in bash (config file)?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15684646/array-like-data-structure-in-bash-config-file)

Comment: Do you have to use Bash?  This sort of thing would be completely trivial with e.g. Ruby and YAML or Python and JSON or Lua or a bunch of other things.

Comment: I think it would be best for it to use Bash for what I am doing. I need to use the screen command and other things related to that.

Comment: Some more detail about what you are actually trying to do would be helpful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

with bash v4, using associative arrays, store the properties from the config file as actual bash variables:

```
$ while read line; do 
    if [[ $line =~ ^"["(.+)"]"$ ]]; then 
        arrname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
        declare -A $arrname
    elif [[ $line =~ ^([_[:alpha:]][_[:alnum:]]*)"="(.*) ]]; then 
        declare ${arrname}[${BASH_REMATCH[1]}]="${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
    fi
done < config.conf

$ echo ${array0[value1]}
asdf

$ echo ${array1[value2]}
5678

$ for i in "${!array0[@]}"; do echo "$i => ${array0[$i]}"; done
value1 => asdf
value2 => jkl

$ for i in "${!array1[@]}"; do echo "$i => ${array1[$i]}"; done
value1 => 1234
value2 => 5678
```

Answer (score 3):

One `eval`-free, 100% pure Bash possibility:

```
#!/bin/bash

die() {
   printf >&2 "%s\n" "$@"
   exit 1
}

aryname=''
linenb=0
while read line; do
   ((++linenb))
   if [[ $line =~ ^[[:space:]]*$ ]]; then
      continue
   elif [[ $line =~ ^\[([[:alpha:]][[:alnum:]]*)\]$ ]]; then
      aryname=${BASH_REMATCH[1]}
      declare -A $aryname
   elif [[ $line =~ ^([^=]+)=(.*)$ ]]; then
      [[ -n aryname ]] || die "*** Error line $linenb: no array name defined"
      printf -v ${aryname}["${BASH_REMATCH[1]}"] "%s" "${BASH_REMATCH[2]}"
   else
      die "*** Error line $linenb: $line"
   fi
done
```

Reads on standard input. If you want to read from a file, change the `done` by:

```
done < "filename"
```

Lines of the form

```
space and funnŷ sÿmbòl=value that will have an equal sign: look = it's funny
```

are allowed

Comment: I like this answer but I find it more convenient to use array0[value1] instead of array0[0]. It better suits my needs. (Updated question)

Comment: @AJFerguson Nice to read this! I actually had to tweak things in a very unnatural way to fit your original requirements! Let me edit the answer to fit your new (and much more natural) requirements.

Comment: @AJFerguson changed (simplified) to fit your new requirements.

Answer (score 1):

You can declare array in bash scripts with

`declare -a <array_name>=(value1 value2 value 3)`

Then you can use them like this

`echo ${<array_name>[index]}`

**Edit:**

Ok, to construct arrays from config file. I would recommend to have a different file for each array you would like to create.

So here are the steps

**1.config file** *(create a file and place your values in it)*

```
100
200
300
```

**2.script file** *(read values from file and prepare an array)*

```
    array=()

    #setup array
    while IFS=$'\n' read -a config
    do
      array+=(${config})
    done < file_name

    #access values
    echo ${array[0]}
    echo ${array[1]}
```

IFS denotes the delimiter 
-a specifies the array name you want to extract to, so that you can access them inside the while loop.

Comment: I understand how to declare and use arrays but my problem is to parse arrays from a file.

Answer (score 0):

I am about to go out, but I think you can do something like this (untested) and maybe someone clever , like @anubhava, will pick it up and finish it off...

```
eval $(gawk -F= '/^\[/{name=gensub(/\[|\]/,"","g");x=0} /=/{print "name[",x++,"]=",$2," "}' config)
```

Basically, when it sees a line starting with "`[`" it picks up the array name in the variable `name` and strips off the square brackets with `gensub()`. Then, when it sees a line with "`=`" in it, it outputs the array name and an increasing index "`x`" for `eval` to pick up.

Gotta dash - look at the examples for `stat -s` [here](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/stat.1.html).